# How to pass the event object to a named function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event handler for the click event. The event handler is a named function instead of an anonymous function. How can I pass the event object to this named function?

```
// usual example
$(".sel").click(function(ev) {
  // do stuff which involves the event
});

// my case
$(".sel").click(myHandler);

function myHandler() {
  // hopefully do stuff which involves the event
}
```

Comment: javascript functions are first class pass them like normal variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Event is passed to the event handling function as an argument by default**

```
function myHandler(evt) {
    // You can use event object here
}
```