# Unable to get the event target property of a named function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, targeting

In the fiddle linked below there's some example code I need to troubleshoot.  I've simplified it a bit from the original code (didn't write) for demo purposes in the fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").children().each(function(i){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var indexItem = i; 

            if(indexItem == 0){
                 displayId();                                  
            }
            if(indexItem == 1){
                displayNode();
            }
            if(indexItem == 2){
                displayNodevalue();
            }
       });
    });
})
function displayId(event){
   // below returns undefined not what I want
   // var $listID = jQuery(this).attr("id"); 
   var $listID = event.target.id;
    alert($listID);
}

function displayNode(event){
    var listNodename = event.target.nodeName;
    alert(listNodename);
}

function displayNodevalue(event){
    var listValue = event.target.nodeValue;
    alert(listValue);
}
```

How do I get the event.target properties for these items?  The console displays:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`

I've googled various possible solutions below. They are good but I'm not finding the answer.

[How to pass the event object to a named function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768295/how-to-pass-the-event-object-to-a-named-function)

[Getting the ID of the element that fired an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239/getting-the-id-of-the-element-that-fired-an-event)

https://api.jquery.com/event.target/

If I've missed the answer in those threads, please let me know.  Seems this question should be answered somewhere, but I'm having trouble locating it. If not, I'd appreciate some help telling me what is wrong with this code and how to get the event target.  Thanks.

[**FIDDLE LINK**](https://jsfiddle.net/vyun59vq/)

Comment: Please don't circumnavigate the warning message. __Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.__

Comment: @Satpal, I didn't notice a warning.  I have no problem posting code, I've been advised in the past when posting to use fiddles or codepen, etc. to display code since it would be easier to debug.  Which is why I put the fiddle in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the event object as a parameter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").children().each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            var indexItem = i;

            if (indexItem == 0) {
                displayId(e);
            }
            if (indexItem == 1) {
                displayNode(e);
            }
            if (indexItem == 2) {
                displayNodevalue();
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sferm4n4/)

---

Also try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fns = [displayId, displayNode, displayNodevalue]
    $("ul").children().click(function (e) {
        var indexItem = $(this).index();
        fns[indexItem] ? fns[indexItem](e) : '';
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sferm4n4/3/)

Comment: Thanks Arun.  I thought I tried that, but I didn't pass the event obj to the click function! Seems I have to wait in order to mark answer

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `each()` is redundant code as you can access the `index` of the clicked element using `$(this).index()`. Then you simply need to capture the event that was raised in the click handler and pass it to your other functions. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").children().click(function (e) {
        var indexItem = $(this).index();

        if (indexItem == 0) {
            displayId(e);
        }
        if (indexItem == 1) {
            displayNode(e);
        }
        if (indexItem == 2) {
            displayNodevalue(e);
        }
    });
})

function displayId(e) {
    var $listID = e.target.id;
    alert($listID);
}

function displayNode(e) {
    var listNodename = e.target.nodeName;
    alert(listNodename);
}

function displayNodevalue(e) {
    var listValue = e.target.nodeValue;
    alert(listValue);
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vyun59vq/1/)

Comment: Is it not better to use `$("ul li")` instead of `$("ul").children()` as only `li` can be immediate child of `ul`

Comment: It probably is, I just used the selector the OP had, assuming there was some other logic behind his choice.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks. +1 Yes the original code was using the children selector, so I just copied/pasted.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a event parameter from the click function to your function like this:

```
$(this).click(function (event) {
   var indexItem = i;
   if (indexItem == 0) {
     displayId(event);
   }
   if (indexItem == 1) {
     displayNode(event);
   }
   if (indexItem == 2) {
     displayNodevalue();
   }
});
```